# How shall I get collaborators of collaborators using mysql?

Tags: mysql

Currently I am in need to find out how to list my (collaborator_a) Collaborators’ (collaborator_b) **Collaborators** and their event instances.

How it currently works:

For "*Collaborator B*"

1. *Collaborator B* clicks a "connect me to the project" button on *Collaborator A* project page.
2. The user ID of *Collaborator A* is saved as **collaborator_a**
3. The user ID of *Collaborator B* is saved as **collaborator_b**
4. The ID of the project *Collaborator B* wants to link to, is saved as **event_instance_id_a**
5. An instance of *Collaborator A’s* project is created for *Collaborator B*. The ID of this new project instance is saved as **event_instance_id_b**

This is all being created for "*Collaborator A*" as well, but ID’s being mirrored.

End.

The tables I have looks something like this:

**collaborator**

```
id  collaborator_a  collaborator_b  event_instance_id_a  event_instance_id_b
--  --------------  --------------  -------------------  -------------------
1   1               2               1                    2
2   2               1               2                    1
3   1               3               1                    3
4   3               1               3                    1
5   6               9               4                    5
6   9               6               5                    4
7   1               9               6                    5
8   9               1               5                    6
```

**event_instance**

```
id  user_id  description
--  -------  --------------
1   1        Some event desc...               
2   2        Some event desc...     
3   3        Some event desc...     
4   6        Some event desc...    
5   9        Some event desc...   
6   1        Some event desc...
```

**user**

```
id  username  
--  --------  
1   username_1           
2   username_2           
3   username_3         
4   username_4     
5   username_5     
6   username_6
7   username_7     
8   username_8     
9   username_9
```

I am able to get my (*collaborator_a*) own Collaborators (*collaborator_b*) and their event instances like this:

Variables

```
$user_id = 1
$event_instance_id_a = 2
```

MySQL

```
SELECT c.*, u.*, e.* 
FROM (collaborator c) 
JOIN event_instance e ON c.event_instance_id_b = e.id 
JOIN user u ON c.collaborator_b = u.id 
WHERE c.event_instance_id_a = $event_instance_id_a 
AND c.collaborator_a = $user_id
```

Any friendly person out there that can help me out getting my collaborators’ collaborator to a specific event instance ID?

Comment: Can you add in the desired data output? Knowing what data should be returned helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're after... but if you're trying to get all the contributors of an event, this should work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d1a0/1:

```
create table event_collaborators (
  event_id int,
  collaborator_id int
);

create table events (
  id int, 
  user_id int,
  description varchar(255) not null
);

create table users (
  id int, 
  username varchar(25) not null
);
```

I've adapted your columns so that it was easier to understand, though by doing so may not answer your question completely.

```
SELECT ec.*, e.*, u.username
FROM event_collaborators AS ec
INNER JOIN events AS e ON ec.event_id = e.id
INNER JOIN users as u ON ec.collaborator_id = u.id
WHERE ec.event_id = 3;
```

Using `*` is a pretty bad idea, but for demonstration purposes it's ok. I also don't like the idea of two big `INNER JOINS` so I'd use an index on the `event_collaborators` mapping table and separate the queries if possible.